# What type to unmarshall xs:time

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I Have an XML that I want to deserialize.
One of the attribute is: `<xs:attribute name="A_anonnceHeureSurv" type="xs:time" use="required" />`
the value is like '20:30:00'

What could be the Java time to unmarshall this attribute?

For now I use a String but I want to know if there is a best solution...

Comment: I'm not sur about the use of java.sql.Time... For me, you can use it when your data come from a DB or is for a DB. In my case I want to expose the object in an API...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the time-zone, then I suggest: [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) otherwise maybe [OffsetTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html).

Comment: Is java 8 LocalTime preferable over joda LocalTime?

Comment: @vikingsteve well, it's now a standard API (which is inspired by JodaTime AFAIK), so I would say: yes

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's - given you are on java 8, naturally :) For java 7 I was recently using joda `DateTime` for `type=xs:dateTime"` types.

Comment: As I say in my response to StanislavL it is to expose the object in an API. So I don't force the users to use Joda... But your answers are good for the others I think, so I accept this one. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @bryce With Java 6 I would recommend Calendar if you don't want to use JodaTime: https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Using_different_datatypes.html. But note that Oracle Java SE 6 (and soon also Oracle Java SE 7) reached EOL.